# xrandr --addmode DP-2 1920x1080_61.00 returns a error

Tags: nvidia, xorg

I have a little bit broken monitor. It can't handle FHD on 60Hz. In Windows I've set 61Hz refresh rate and it works fine on it's normal FHD resolution But in linux it's won't.My system is ubuntu 18.04 desktop. Virtualization enabled in BIOS settings, but I think it's about other things (emulation for example)
[my actions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/npSFx.png)

what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: To start with, which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, et al.) , and which release number? Are you using virtualization, and if so, which package? Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question. Please do not use Add Comment.

Comment: Current: 3280x1050. Do you have other mon9tors connected? Depending on the hardware, you may have trouble, configuring more than two monitors at the same time.

Comment: No, only two monitors. My GPU - gtx 1060, so connect even 3 or 4 monitors will not a problem.